# Concatenating difference rows with multi-column keys

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a `data.frame` where if I take multiple columns together (say `a`, `b`, and `c`), then I have an identifier that is unique to two different rows (that differ on column `name`, and a bunch of value columns `x`, `y`, and `z`).

I'd like to take the difference on the value columns, preserve the key columns, and give the name column a new value like `diff`.

So for example, suppose I have the following data:

```
    a b c    x    y    z  name
 1  1 M J  0.0  1.0  2.0 alpha
 2  1 M K  0.1  0.9  2.0 alpha
 3  1 O J  0.2  0.8  2.0 alpha
 4  1 O K  0.3  0.7  2.0 alpha
 5  2 M J  0.4  0.6  2.0 alpha
 6  2 M K  0.5  0.5  2.0 alpha
 7  2 O J  0.6  0.4  2.0 alpha
 8  2 O K  0.7  0.3  2.0 alpha
 9  1 M J  0.0  2.0  1.0  beta
10  1 M K  0.1  1.9  3.0  beta
11  1 O J  0.2  1.8  1.0  beta
12  1 O K  0.3  1.7  3.0  beta
13  2 M J  0.4  1.6  1.0  beta
14  2 M K  0.5  1.5  3.0  beta
15  2 O J  0.6  1.4  1.0  beta
16  2 O K  0.7  1.3  3.0  beta
```

Then I want the new data frame to be:

```
    a b c    x    y    z  name
 1  1 M J  0.0  1.0  2.0 alpha
 2  1 M K  0.1  0.9  2.0 alpha
 3  1 O J  0.2  0.8  2.0 alpha
 4  1 O K  0.3  0.7  2.0 alpha
 5  2 M J  0.4  0.6  2.0 alpha
 6  2 M K  0.5  0.5  2.0 alpha
 7  2 O J  0.6  0.4  2.0 alpha
 8  2 O K  0.7  0.3  2.0 alpha
 9  1 M J  0.0  2.0  1.0  beta
10  1 M K  0.1  1.9  3.0  beta
11  1 O J  0.2  1.8  1.0  beta
12  1 O K  0.3  1.7  3.0  beta
13  2 M J  0.4  1.6  1.0  beta
14  2 M K  0.5  1.5  3.0  beta
15  2 O J  0.6  1.4  1.0  beta
16  2 O K  0.7  1.3  3.0  beta
17  1 M J  0.0 -1.0  1.0  diff
18  1 M K  0.0 -1.0 -1.0  diff
19  1 O J  0.0 -1.0  1.0  diff
20  1 O K  0.0 -1.0 -1.0  diff
21  2 M J  0.0 -1.0  1.0  diff
22  2 M K  0.0 -1.0 -1.0  diff
23  2 O J  0.0 -1.0  1.0  diff
24  2 O K  0.0 -1.0 -1.0  diff
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is your data always sorted in order? If so, then you can make some simplifying assumptions and not have to worry about careful matching. Just subtract the bottom half from the top half.

Comment: Hm, yes, but that won't that also subtract the index columns? I suppose that I could just extract the relevant ones and paste them into a copy of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is always sorted and ballanced. Then this should work

```
half<-1:(nrow(df)/2)
rbind(
    df,
    cbind( 
        df[half, 1:3], 
        df[half, 4:6] - df[half+half[length(half)], 4:6], 
        name="diff"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make each column individually:

```
colx = ave(df$x, paste(df$a, df$b, df$c), FUN=function(x) x[1]-x[2])
coly = ave(df$y, paste(df$a, df$b, df$c), FUN=function(x) x[1]-x[2])
colz = ave(df$z, paste(df$a, df$b, df$c), FUN=function(x) x[1]-x[2])
```

And then put them together:

```
df2 = subset(df, name=="alpha")
df2$name = "diff"
df2$x = colx[1:(length(colx)/2)]
df2$y = coly[1:(length(coly)/2)]
df2$z = colz[1:(length(colz)/2)]
```

Now join to original

```
df = rbind(df, df2)
```

That gives:

```
   a b c   x    y  z name
1  1 m j 0.0  1.0  2    a
2  1 m k 0.1  0.9  2    a
3  1 o j 0.2  0.8  2    a
4  1 o k 0.3  0.7  2    a
5  2 m j 0.4  0.6  2    a
6  2 m k 0.5  0.5  2    a
7  2 o j 0.6  0.4  2    a
8  2 o k 0.7  0.3  2    a
9  1 m j 0.0  2.0  1    b
10 1 m k 0.1  1.9  3    b
11 1 o j 0.2  1.8  1    b
12 1 o k 0.3  1.7  3    b
13 2 m j 0.4  1.6  1    b
14 2 m k 0.5  1.5  3    b
15 2 o j 0.6  1.4  1    b
16 2 o k 0.7  1.3  3    b
17 1 m j 0.0 -1.0  1 diff
18 1 m k 0.0 -1.0 -1 diff
19 1 o j 0.0 -1.0  1 diff
20 1 o k 0.0 -1.0 -1 diff
21 2 m j 0.0 -1.0  1 diff
22 2 m k 0.0 -1.0 -1 diff
23 2 o j 0.0 -1.0  1 diff
24 2 o k 0.0 -1.0 -1 diff
```

Comment: You don't need that paste() in `ave`; `colx = ave(df$x, df$a, df$b, df$c, FUN=function(x) x[1]-x[2])` should work just as well without all the unnecessary string concatenation.